# Recognize second click event in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments

I am programming my first android app. It is a quiz app, in which a question with 4 answer options is displayed.
I would like to display the correct answer as soon as one of the buttons is clicked and then display the next question when the button is clicked again.

---

**At the moment the correct answer and the next question are displayed at the same time.**

```
public class ACEInhibitors extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
List<Question> quesList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc, rdd;
Button checkBtn;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question, null);

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    quesList = db.getAllACEQuestions();
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rda = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio3);

    rda.setOnClickListener(this);
    rdb.setOnClickListener(this);
    rdc.setOnClickListener(this);
    rdd.setOnClickListener(this);

    setQuestionView();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio0:
            // Happening for the first click
            // Set colors according to correct answer
            rda.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            rdc.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            rdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTA())) {
                rda.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTB())) {
                rdb.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTC())) {
                rdc.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            } else if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(currentQ.getOPTD())) {
                rdd.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }

            // Supposed to happen for the second click
            // Display the next question
            currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
            break;
    }
}

private void setQuestionView() {
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
    qid++;
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

---

I am really new to android and java programming and would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do below steps to achieve desired results

1. Add one button initially with visibility gone.
2. Now replace `setQuestionView()` call from onClick with `button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
3. Add click listener to button.
4. On button click call `setQuestionView()` again.

Comment: That is a fantastic idea! Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as I can!